# TextView TextAllCaps crashing application

Tags: android, android-layout, text, textview

I'm getting very strange behaviour with my `TextView`.  I can't seem to find the cause as most other issues with this stacktrace are to do with `EditText`.

This is in my layout:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/transaction_card_scan_message_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:lines="5"
        android:textColor="@color/transaction_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/transaction_card_scan_title_textSize"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>
```

I am getting this error:

```
2019-10-21 17:47:32.177 18455-18455/com.iaxept.contactless E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.iaxept.contactless, PID: 18455
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance(Paint.java:2986)
    at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:719)
    at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:873)
    at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:387)
    at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:277)
    at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:251)
    at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:1094)
    at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:383)
    at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAccelerated(Editor.java:1903)
    at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:1822)
    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:6691)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18319)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17297)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3950)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3930)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17260)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3950)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3930)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17260)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3950)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3930)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17260)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3950)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3930)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17260)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3950)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3930)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17260)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3950)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3930)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17260)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3950)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3930)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17260)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3950)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3930)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17260)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:666)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:672)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:780)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3112)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2908)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2502)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7051)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I've tried `messageView.setTransformationMethod(new AllCapsTransformationMethod(getParentActivity()))` to no avail.  It's really strange as it works without issue when the text is a mix of lower and upper case and the stacktrace isn't exactly useful.

Comment: Don't know if it's smart thing to do, but as a workaround you can check the text, to see if it contains both upper and lower case letters, and only then call your function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but which function are you referring to?

Comment: The one you claim works with a mixture of upper and lower case letters.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough.  The TextView works normally without `textAllCaps`, but not with it.  The function I tried didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is an Android OS bug, as when I use `toUpperCase()` in all of my `setText()` or `append()` calls there is no crash and therefore works as a temporary solution.  However, the `android:textAllCaps="true"` issue persists and needs to be fixed.